# Can we have another MANY-TO-MANY relationship between a junction table with some pivot columns and another third table?

Tags: mysql, laravel, database, many-to-many

I am building an application in Laravel:

Can we have the primary ID inside the pivot table that is for if we want this pivot table's primary ID in another table as a foreign ID?

In a scenario where another table is also a pivot table having the current pivot table ID as foreign ID and some other table ID as foreign ID.

For more clarification:
Table1, Table2, Table3
Table1_Table2 (Pivot Table between Table1 and Table2)
Table1_Table2_User (Pivot Table between Table1_Table2 and Table3)

Table1:
id, name, etc

Table2:
id, name, etc

Users:
id, name, etc

Table1_Table2:(Intermediate table with pivot columns)
id, table1_id, table2_id, currentActive, lastActive

Table1_Table2_User:(Intermediate table extending above intermediate table with another table with some pivot columns)
id, table1_table2_id, user_id, actionPending

Also, is that the correct approach?

Can someone provide me the models for Table1_Table2 and Table1_Table2_User ?

Trying to make a schema of an application where more than 5 to 6 tables are related with each other.

Comment: Sure you can. Be sure you make model that extends Pivot (check in docs) then make another manyToMany relation just as any other one.

Comment: @Tpojka can you also answer me on this?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77914039/in-laravel-can-i-create-onetomany-relation-with-junction-table-instead-of-belong